# Issues with structure variable initialization

Tags: c, struct

For some reason my struct variable doesn't reliably hold its values

I've tried designated initializers and doing it "manually" in a separate function. The odd thing is, it works for one variable, but doesn't for another.

```c
struct triangle;

struct vertex{
    int tag;
    double x;
    double y;
    int isBorder; //0 if it isn't, 1 if it is
};

struct edge{
    struct vertex *a;
    struct vertex *b;
    struct triangle *triangle1;
    struct triangle *triangle2;
    int refinementOrder;
    int isBorder; // 0 false, 1 true
    int isOdd; //0 false; 1 true

};

struct triangle{ 
    struct vertex *vertex1;
    struct vertex *vertex2;
    struct vertex *vertex3;
    struct edge *edge1;
    struct edge *edge2;
    struct edge *edge3;
    struct triangle *neighbour1;
    struct triangle *neighbour2;
    struct triangle *neighbour3;
    int type; //0 - even/a ; 1 - odd/b
};
```

```c
struct edge *newE1, *newE2 = {0}, *newE3;

newE1 = malloc(sizeof(newE1));
newE2 = malloc(sizeof(newE2));
newE3 = malloc(sizeof(newE3));

*newE1 = (struct edge) {v1, com, NULL, NULL, refinementOrder+1, 0, 0};
*newE2 = (struct edge) {v2, com, NULL, NULL, refinementOrder+1, 0, 0};
//initEdge(newE2, v2, com, refinementOrder+1);
*newE3 = (struct edge) {v3, com, NULL, NULL, refinementOrder+1, 0, 0};
//newE2->isBorder = 0;
printf("%d\n", newE2->isBorder);
```

Even though I initialize newE2 with 0 in isBorder, the print statement gives me something that looks like a memory address. The odd thing is, it does give 0 if I try newE1. It also gives me 0 if I manually assign it 0 in this function. If I manually assign it 0 in a separate function (done in initEdge(...) it doesn't print 0.

Comment: `sizeof(newE1)` is the size of *pointer*.

Comment: try `newE2 = malloc(sizeof(struct edge));` instead.

Comment: @Blaze Or `sizeof(*newE1)`

Comment: `struct edge *newE1, *newE2 = {0}, *newE3;` ...just, why?

Comment: sizeof(*newE1) has indeed fixed it... thanks a LOT!

Comment: @EugeneSh. No, that's fine.  It dereferences the pointer and writes to the pointed-to object, not the pointer itself.

Comment: @dbush Ah, you are right. Weird way of initializing struct, but probably a legit one...

Comment: @SouravGhosh At that point I was just trying to see if I could make it 0 by any means necessary since I read somewhere that if you didn't pass any values, it would initialize everything to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not allocating enough space for your sturctures:

```
newE1 = malloc(sizeof(newE1));
newE2 = malloc(sizeof(newE2));
newE3 = malloc(sizeof(newE3));
```

The variables `newE1` is a pointer, so `sizeof(newE1)` gives you the size of a pointer, not what it points to (and the same for `newE2` and `newE3`).  Pointers are typically either 4 or 8 bytes in size, so this is most likely less than the size of the struct.

As a result, when you attempt to write to particular members of the struct, you write past the end of the allocated memory block.  This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

To allocate the proper amount of memory:

```
newE1 = malloc(sizeof(*newE1));
newE2 = malloc(sizeof(*newE2));
newE3 = malloc(sizeof(*newE3));
```

Note also the use of `sizeof(*newE1)` instead of `sizeof(struct edge)`, as this is more resilient in the event the name of the struct changes or is replaced with a typedef.

Answer (score 0):

It was just bad malloc-ing. I was malloc-ing space for a pointer, not the struct.

Using `malloc(sizeof(*newE1))` fixed the issues.